# How to remove duplicate words in an array?

Tags: python, list

I have these arrays in python:

```
noDuplicateArr = ['"foo barr', '"foo corp', '"barr corp']
wordsArr = ['"fool barr', '"fool corp"']
```

Now what's the best approach to not append in `noDuplicateArr` the words `"fool barr"` & `"fool corp"` because `"barr"` and `"corp"` are already present in `noDuplicateArr`?

Comment: `set(noDuplicateArr + wordsArr)`

Comment: This page has all you need
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists

Comment: @jordanm `list(set(noDuplicateArr + wordsArr))` to make a list

Comment: This should not have been closed. He isn't looking to remove duplicates in a list. He wants to avoid appending new strings to a list of strings of the encountered words (substrings) already exist in the list.

Answer (score 1):

To better phrase this, you want to prevent appending a string to a list of strings if it contains a word/substring that already exists in it. You'll need to use a set to keep track of words that have already been added.

```
noDuplicateArr = ['"foo barr', '"foo corp', '"barr corp']
wordsArr = ['"fool barr', '"fool corp"']

seen_words = set()
for words in noDuplicateArr:
  words = words.strip('"')
  seen_words |= set(words.split())

for words in wordsArr:
  seen = False
  words = words.strip('"')
  for word in words.split():
    if word in seen_words:
      seen = True
      continue
  if not seen:
    noDuplicateArr.append(words)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I had this use case, I got this
```
noDuplicateArr = ['foo', 'poo']
wordsArr = ['foo bar'] -> should not be appended

noDuplicateArr = ['bar foo', 'poo']
wordsArr = ['bar'] -> this should replace all words with bar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list(set(noDuplicateArr.extend(wordsArr)))
```

This will give you an array with unique entries only.